# Taking partial derivatives to the thousand times.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was just wondering how I would solve a question like this?

$$\frac {\partial^{1000}f}{\partial x^{500}\partial y^{500}}$$ Where the partial derivative is $$e^{2x-4/y}-y^{12}x^{21}$$

Comment: Equivalent to $2^{500}\exp(2x) \partial_y^{500} \exp(-4/y)$. The y-derivative seems annoying.

Comment: It seems involved. Maybe it is possible to relate it to Hermite polynomials by changing variables or something?

Answer (score 0):

As said by eyeballfrog, the derivatives on $x$ are easy as the first term is separable and the derivatives of the exponential are immediate. The polynomial term quickly vanishes.

On the opposite the derivatives of $e^{-4/y}$ on $y$ are problematic as they involve a complex recurrence relation on the coefficients. They are of the form

$$P\left(\frac1y\right)e^{-4/y}$$ where $P$ is a polynomial with terms of degree $501$ to $1000$ and integer coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Considering
$$f_n=\frac{\partial ^n\left(e^{-\frac{a}{y}}\right)}{\partial y^n}$$ we have
$$\frac 1a\,{y^{2n}}\, e^{\frac{a}{y}} f_n=a^{n-1}+ P_{n-1}(y)$$

The first polynomials are listed below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & -2 y \\
 3 & -6 a y+6 y^2 \\
 4 & -12 a^2 y+36 a y^2-24 y^3 \\
 5 & -20 a^3 y+120 a^2 y^2-240 a y^3+120 y^4 \\
 6 & -30 a^4 y+300 a^3 y^2-1200 a^2 y^3+1800 a y^4-720 y^5 \\
 7 & -42 a^5 y+630 a^4 y^2-4200 a^3 y^3+12600 a^2 y^4-15120 a y^5+5040
   y^6 
\end{array}
\right)$$ where we can notice clear patterns.

For example

- the first term corresponds to $-n(n+1)a^{n-2}y$
- the second term corresponds to $\frac 12 n^2(n^2-1)a^{n-3}y^2$
- the last term corresponds to $(-1)^{n-1} n! y^{n-1}$

You could find most of them in $OEIS$.

**Edit**

We can also write
$$\frac 1a\,{y^{2n}}\, e^{\frac{a}{y}} f_n=a^{n-1}\left(1+ z\, Q_{n-2}(z)\right) \qquad z=a y$$ and the polynomials are
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & -2 \\
 3 & -6+6 z \\
 4 & -12+36 z-24 z^2 \\
 5 & -20+120 z-240 z^2+120 z^3 \\
 6 & -30+300 z-1200 z^2+1800 z^3-720 z^4 \\
 7 & -42+630 z-4200 z^2+12600 z^3-15120 z^4+5040 z^5 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Only the computation of ${d^n\over dy^n}e^{-4/y}$ causes difficulties. I claim that
$${d^n\over dy^n}e^{-4/y}=y^{-2n}\>Q_n(y)\>e^{-4/y}\qquad(n\geq0)\tag{1}$$
where $Q_0(y)\equiv1$, and $Q_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$  $\,(n\geq1)$. For $(1)$ to be true we need
$${d\over dy}\left(y^{-2n}\>Q_n(y)\>e^{-4/y}\right)=y^{-2(n+1)}Q_{n+1}(y)\>e^{-4/y}\ .$$
This amounts to
$$-2n y^{-2n-1}Q_n(y)+y^{-2n}Q_n'(y)+y^{-2n}Q_n(y)\>4y^{-2}=y^{-2n-2} Q_{n+1}(y)\ ,$$
where we have omitted the nonzero factor $e^{-4/y}$. In this way we obtain the recursion
$$Q_{n+1}(y)=(4-2n y)Q_n(y)+y^2 Q_n'(y)\ .$$
This shows that $Q_1(y)=4$, and that for $n\geq1$ the function $Q_{n+1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ when $Q_n$ had degree $n-1$.